# Deploying ASP.NET Web API to IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I developed a Web API and am trying to deploy it to my web server. Is there a forward steps to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a forward steps to do that

Yes, right click on the web project and then on the `Publish ...` button in the context menu. Then follow the steps. Here's an [`overview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698.aspx) of the process on MSDN that you might go through.

Comment: thanx a lot for replay ,but i don't have any profile in publish option

Comment: Then go ahead and create new one.